# How to derive simple formula for $\frac{1^3}{1^4 + 4} - \frac{3^3}{3^4 + 4} + \frac{5^3}{5^4 + 4} - ··· +\frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)^3}{(2n+1)^4 + 4}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been reading the art of computer programming and this problem showed up.

$$\frac{1^3}{1^4 + 4} - \frac{3^3}{3^4 + 4} + \frac{5^3}{5^4 + 4} - ··· +\frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)^3}{(2n+1)^4 + 4}$$

$$ = \frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{4(n+1)^2 + 1}$$

The problem is how this answer showed up. I have to know how to derive this.

I've been using calculus and i don't think this is right way to solve.

I really appreciate your help with this!

Edit : I have to specify i like to know how to get answer from scratch.

Comment: This seems like a natural for induction...

Comment: Could induction work? Let $f(n)=\dfrac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{4(n+1)^2+1}$ then we ought to show that $$f(n)-f(n-1)=\frac{(-1)^n (2n+1)^3}{(2n+1)^4+4}$$

Comment: @MrPie I have to specify i like to know how to get answer from scratch. Can i get help?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I have to specify i like to know how to get answer from scratch. Can i get help?

Comment: I think the key is factorization and telescoping. Working on it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac{x^{3}}{x^{4}+4}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{x-1}{(x-1)^{2}+1}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{x+1}{(x+1)^{2}+1}
$$

Sum the first few terms and see if you can recognize the telescoping pattern i.e. terms cancelling each other.

Comment: Thanks! It really helped. but may i ask how did you get telescoping series?

Comment: @Quanta I obtained the denominator using Sophie Germain identity, in case you need it

Comment: It seems a bit rich to attach her name to a piece of high-achool algebra.  She solved a big part of Fermat's Last Theorem 200 years ago.

Comment: @Quanta $(x+2)-1=x+1$ so the second terms on the right cancel the first term on the right for the next $x$. So on and so forth until you are left with far less terms

Comment: @Empy2 Yes she was a great mathematician and I think we can appreciate her contribution, both the simpler and the more sophisticated ones

Answer (score 0):

I get it
with an additional
$\dfrac18$.

Here is the
(somewhat messy)
calculation.

Want to show that
$\frac{1^3}{1^4 + 4} - \frac{3^3}{3^4 + 4} + \frac{5^3}{5^4 + 4} - ··· +\frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)^3}{(2n+1)^4 + 4}
= \frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{4(n+1)^2 + 1}
$.

The sum is
$s(n)
=\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{(-1)^{k}(2k+1)^3}{(2k+1)^4+4}
$.

Since
$x^4+4
=(x^2 - 2 x + 2) (x^2 + 2 x + 2)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
(2k+1)^4+4
&=((2k+1)^2 - 2 (2k+1) + 2) ((2k+1)^2 + 2 (2k+1) + 2)\\
&=(4k^2+4k+1 - (4k+2) + 2) (4k^2+4k+1+(4k+2)+2)\\
&=(4k^2+1) (4k^2+8k+5)\\
&=(4k^2+1) (4k^2+8k+4+1)\\
&=(4k^2+1) (4(k+1)^2+1)\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac1{(2k+1)^4+4}
&=\dfrac1{(4k^2+1) (4(k+1)^2+1)}\\
&=-\dfrac{2k-1}{8(4k^2+1)}+\dfrac{2k+3}{8(4(k+1)^2+1)}
\qquad\text{(according to Wolfy)}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{(2k+1)^3}{(2k+1)^4+4}
&=-\dfrac{(2k-1)(2k+1)^3}{8(4k^2+1)}+\dfrac{(2k+3)(2k+1)^3}{8(4(k+1)^2+1)}\\
&=-\dfrac{(2k-1)(2k+1)(2k+1)^2}{8(4k^2+1)}+\dfrac{(2k+3)(2k+1)(2k+1)^2}{8(4(k+1)^2+1)}\\
&=-\dfrac{(4k^2-1)(2k+1)^2}{8(4k^2+1)}+\dfrac{((2k+2)^2-1)(2k+1)^2}{8(4(k+1)^2+1)}\\
&=-\dfrac{(4k^2-1)(2k+1)^2}{8(4k^2+1)}+\dfrac{(4(k+1)^2-1)(2k+1)^2}{8(4(k+1)^2+1)}\\
\text{Therefore}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{(-1)^{k}(2k+1)^3}{(2k+1)^4+4}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\left(-\dfrac{(4k^2-1)(2k+1)^2}{8(4k^2+1)}+\dfrac{(4(k+1)^2-1)(2k+1)^2}{8(4(k+1)^2+1)}\right)\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\dfrac{(4k^2-1)(2k+1)^2}{8(4k^2+1)}+\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\dfrac{(4(k+1)^2-1)(2k+1)^2}{8(4(k+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k+1}\dfrac{(4k^2-1)(2k+1)^2}{8(4k^2+1)}+\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\dfrac{(4(k+1)^2-1)(2(k+1)-1)^2}{8(4(k+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k+1}\dfrac{(4k^2-1)(2k+1)^2}{8(4k^2+1)}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1}\dfrac{(4k^2-1)(2k-1)^2}{8(4k^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k+1}\dfrac{(4k^2-1)}{8(4k^2+1)}((2k+1)^2+(2k-1)^2)+ (-1)^{n}\dfrac{(4(n+1)^2-1)(2(n+1)-1)^2}{8(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k+1}\dfrac{(4k^2-1)}{8(4k^2+1)}(8k^2+2)+ (-1)^{n}\dfrac{(4(n+1)^2-1)(2(n+1)-1)^2}{8(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\dfrac14\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k+1}(4k^2-1)+ (-1)^{n}\dfrac{(4(n+1)^2-1)(2n+1)^2}{8(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(4n^2+4n-1)}{8}+ (-1)^{n}\dfrac{(4(n+1)^2-1)(2n+1)^2}{8(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(4n^2+4n-1)}{8}+ (-1)^{n}\dfrac{(4(n+1)^2+1-2)(2n+1)^2}{8(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(4n^2+4n-1)}{8}+ (-1)^{n}\dfrac{(4(n+1)^2+1-2)(2n+1)^2}{8(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(4n^2+4n-1)}{8}+ (-1)^{n}\dfrac{(4(n+1)^2+1)(2n+1)^2}{8(4(n+1)^2+1)}-(-1)^{n}\dfrac{2(2n+1)^2}{8(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(4n^2+4n-1)}{8}+ (-1)^{n}\dfrac{(2n+1)^2}{8}-(-1)^{n}\dfrac{2(2n+1)^2}{8(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(4n^2+4n-1-(2n+1)^2)}{8}-(-1)^{n}\dfrac{2(2n+1)^2}{8(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{4}-(-1)^{n}\dfrac{(2n+1)^2}{4(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{4}-(-1)^{n}\dfrac{4n^2+4n+1}{4(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{4}-(-1)^{n}\dfrac{4n^2+8n+5-4n-4}{4(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{4}-(-1)^{n}\dfrac{4(n+1)^2+1-4(n+1)}{4(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{4}-(-1)^{n}\dfrac{4(n+1)^2+1}{4(4(n+1)^2+1)}+(-1)^{n}\dfrac{4(n+1)}{4(4(n+1)^2+1)}\\
&=\dfrac18+\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{4}-(-1)^{n}\dfrac14+(-1)^{n}\dfrac{(n+1)}{4(n+1)^2+1}\\
&=\dfrac18+(-1)^{n}\dfrac{(n+1)}{4(n+1)^2+1}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: If we put n = 0 then $\frac{1}{5}$ is not equal to $\frac{1}{8} -\frac{1}{5}$. did range of n changed somehow?

Comment: I sincerely thank you for your time, but $\frac{1}{4} \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^{k+1}(4k^2 - 1) = \frac{(−1)^{n+1}(4n^2+4n−1)}{8}$ does sum of alternating series can be treated like non-alternating series? If so, how?